# How to keep track of position from a template to a different template (2)?

Tags: xslt, xslt-2.0

Follow on question to: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71635891/how-to-keep-track-of-position-from-a-template-to-a-different-template?noredirect=1#comment126614972_71635891](https://www.stackoverflow.com/)

My new problem is, there could be more than one simplePath in a jump and I want all simplePath inside a jump to start
from the same position. My current is issue is that I'm not competent enough to translate my current idea into XSL, I added in comment in the XSLT code what I'm trying to achieve

```
         
                   D --- E --- F              K --- L --- M --- N --- O
                  /             \           /              
A --- B --- C--- /               \ -- J ---/               
                 \               /         \
                  \             /           \
                   G --- H --- I              Q --- R --- S 

<root>
    <simplePath>
        <point>A</point>
        <point>B</point>
        <point>C</point>
    </simplePath>
    <jump>
        <simplePath>
            <point>D</point>
            <point>E</point>
            <point>F</point>
        </simplePath>

        <simplePath>
            <point>G</point>
            <point>H</point>
            <point>I</point>
        </simplePath>
    </jump>
    <simplePath>
        <point>J</point>
    </simplePath>

</root>
```

expected output

```
A : 0
B : 50
C : 100

D : 300
E : 350
F : 400

Dbis : 300
Ebis : 350
Fbis : 400

G : 600
```

poor attempt :

```
    <xsl:template match="/root">
        <xsl:call-template name="process">
            <xsl:with-param name="points" select=".//point"/>
        </xsl:call-template>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template name="process">
        <xsl:param name="points" />
        <xsl:param name="total" select="0"/>
        <xsl:param name="savePos" select="0"/>
        <!-- new param -->
        <!-- output -->
        <xsl:value-of select="boolean($points[1]/ancestor::jump)"/>
        <xsl:value-of select="$points[1]"/>
        <xsl:text> :  </xsl:text>
        <xsl:value-of select="$total"/>
        <!-- recursive call -->
        <xsl:if test="count($points) > 1">
            <xsl:text>&#10;</xsl:text>
            <xsl:call-template name="process">
                <xsl:with-param name="points" select="$points[position() > 1]"/>
                <xsl:with-param name="total" select="if(boolean($points[1]/ancestor::jump) != boolean($points[2]/ancestor::jump)) then $total + 200 else $total + 50"/>
                <!-- my "attempt" -->
                <!-- I want to save the pos of total IF it's the first point of the first simplePath in a Jump -->
                <xsl:with-param name="savePos" select=""/>
                <!-- Next, I will add a new "if condition" here 
                <xsl:with-param name="total" select="if(boolean($points[1]/ancestor::jump) != boolean($points[2]/ancestor::jump)) 
                then 
                >>>>if I'm not in the first simplePath of "jump", and it's the first "point" of this "simplePath" then 
                        $total = $savePos
                    else
                        $total + 200 
                else 
                    $total + 50"/>
                - -->
            </xsl:call-template>
        </xsl:if>
    </xsl:template>
```

Comment: This is not a well-defined problem. What if the number of `point`s in the 2 `simplePath`s within a `jump` is not equal?

Comment: Ah yes... I think there is an issue with my XML, I added above the XML what I'm trying to represent. Can you tell me you think about it ? I don't know how I can do it differently